# vscode automatic type acquisition for jest

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have vscode 1.9 and I want to have intellisense for jest tests. The problem is that `describe`, `it`, `expect` etc are globally available in jest and you don't need to `import` them in your test files. So vscode will not show intellisense for them.

Is there any configuration for globals for automatic type acquisition?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have a few options in this case:

Add `jest` to your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jest": "^18.1.0"
}
```

This only works if you are working JavaScript and do not have a `tsconfig.json`.

---

Install `@types/jest`

```sh
$ npm install -D @types/jest
```

This should work for both JavaScript and TypeScript projects. However `@types` but may be disabled by a `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json`: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

---

Create a `jsconfig.json` file in the root of your workspace to specifically include jest:

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jest"
        ]
    }
}
```

This will only work for JavaScript projects when automatic typings acquisition is enabled.

All of these should allow VSCode to pick up jest's typings without an `import` or `require`

Comment: That third option of editing `jsconfig.json` appeared to completely turn off auto-completion for me (including for jest).  Any ideas?

Comment: Of the three options, only the second one worked for me: `npm install @types/jest`.

Comment: The third option worked for me. Note that I had `jest-cli` in `devDependencies`. Also, I haven't tried the second option.

Comment: Yes, some of these may not work depending on how your project is setup (such as do you have a tsconfig/jsconfig, are you using TypeScript vs JavaScript) I'll add a few notes on this. Also, if you don't see one of these working as expected, please open a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: The second option worked for me while neither of the other ones did. I'm on vscode v1.14

Comment: Why does Automatic Type Acquisition only work for JavaScript and not for TypeScript? I'm using the same `tsconfig.json` as you are above.

Comment: TypeScript expects you to manage typings manually since they are required for compile. You can also try setting `"typeAcquisition": { "enable": true }` to force enable it

Comment: Second solution (`npm i -D @types/jest`) worked great - thanks!

Comment: First solution does not work with latest Jest version (25.3.0) because included types seems to be broken. Second solution always works for me. Third solution works only if Jest is not included as dependency. Check https://github.com/cedricmn/jest-vscode-ata for more details.

Comment: @Jing how did you use it. when i run npm run test it says jest not found.

Answer (score 6):

I tried installing the `@types/jest`, and it did work, but the problem is that it resulted in the jest suggestions appearing in my `.js` files as well. I couldn't figure out how to get global suggestions for `test`, `expect`, etc. in only `.test.js` files but *not* `.js` files.

So I decided to just manually import each jest global I was going to use in each `.test.js` file, which allowed the suggestions to appear with types but avoided having the suggestions appear in the `.js` files:

`import { test, expect } from '@jest/globals'`

Answer (score 1):

npm install -D @types/jest

edit jest.config.js

```
  typeAcquisition: {
    include: ['jest'],
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the tsconfig.json, ensure you add the `jest` entry to the list of `types`.

For example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es2022"],
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "outDir": "build"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```