# Typescript is not picking up Jest types

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, config

### The Problem

I am trying to setup a typescript project with jest. However typescript does not seem to pickup the jest types from `@types/jest`, which is highlighting my keywords giving me the following error:

`Cannot find name 'test'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try 'npm i @types/jest' or 'npm i @types/mocha'. ts(2582)`

[image]

**Notes:**

- I am using VS Code
- I have installed @types/jest
- I have attempted to reinstall all my packages
- I have reloaded my editor
- Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "types": ["jest"],
  "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"],
}
```

- Here is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
};
```

- Here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"targets": {"node": "current"}}],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
}
```

- Here are the dev dependencies in my package.json

[image]

My test runs fine with `npm run test`, But it is still an annoying issue which I imagine is just a missing `./` in one of my configurations or something. Bit new to typescript/jest though so could be something else. Hopefully I have provided enough info, but am happy to add more if necessary Any help would be appreciated, cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024526/vscode-automatic-type-acquisition-for-jest

Comment: @StefanWang I have installed `@types/jest` already and have jest as a dependency in my package json. I attempted the typeAquisition solution, but no luck there either  thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Your tsconfig is wrong. I doubt 3 years later you still have this problem but I just ran into it myself and found the solution inspired by this question. I posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert, but I was experiencing the same issue (albeit not the same setup) after I modified the typeRoots property and I was able to get it to work by including "@types/jest" in the "types" property of tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "outDir": "./dist",                        
    "rootDir": "./",                      
    "strict": true,                           
    "typeRoots": [      
    "./node_modules/@types/",
    "./src/@types/"
    ],                       
    "types": ["jest", "node", "@types/jest"],                          
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  
    "skipLibCheck": true,                    
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  
},
"exclude": ["node_modules"],
"include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Please use proper format for JSON, it's hard to read. Also exclude is useless with that include and your `types` has jest twice.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is facing a similar issue, please check the following fields in your `tsconfig`

```json
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
```

Make sure you have included the file:

```json
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
```

Lastly check if you have specified `typeRoots` which by default points to `./node_modules/@types` and `types` includes jest

Comment: Exclude: Specifies an array of filenames or patterns that should be skipped when resolving include (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude). So no need to make sure both are defined.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance, that the dependency tree got corrupted.
Kill `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`.
Then run `npm i`.

Comment: And also maybe try restarting TS server

Answer (score 0):

`typeRoots` is part of `compilerOptions`, check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots. Your config should be like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"],
  },
}
```

Every under `/@types` will be included, no need to also specify `types`. In case you want to include only jest, the correct term is `@types/jest`. It also belongs to `compilerOptions`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],
    "types": ["@types/jest"],
  },
}
```